# No Audio on HP ENVY m6-p113dx Running Newly Installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, sound, hp

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my HP ENVY m6-p113dx laptop. The installation went great, and everything on my laptop works perfectly except that I cannot get any audio on the built in speakers on my laptop. The audio worked fine in Windoze before I reformatted the drive and installed Ubuntu. The past couple of days, I have been trying most of the tried and true methods from discussion boards like this one to resolve the issue. I used pavucontrol to check audio levels, I reinstalled pulseaudio and ALSA, etc. Tried all the suggestions at the link below:

[https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-no-sound-issue-ubuntu/][1]

Unfortunately, nothing has worked to fix the problem. I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu, so it is certainly possible there is a simple fix that I have missed. Has anyone else been able to resolve this problem on a similar HP laptop? Here is my inxi audio info:

```
nathan@nathan-HP-ENVY-m6-Notebook:~$ inxi -A
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Kabini HDMI/DP Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD Family 15h Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-30-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

I appreciate any suggestions or tips that you may have.

Comment: OK, made some progress today by replacing pulseaudio wth pipewire. Audio now works when I plug in headphones, but still cannot play audio on internal speakers. :( Thoughts?